# SVM for web application

Tags: machine-learning

I'm working on a project where I train a text classifier and I need to create a web app to let the user enter text for classification. Currently all the code is written in Python and I'm using scikit-learn library. I've encountered a problem installing the scikit-learn on heroku, in order for my Python code to run on the server. I don't mind changing everything (Python language, Flask web framework, scikit learning library, heroku web-app hosting services), I just need to get this thing to work :)

Do any one of you in CV community had any experience in making a web-app that uses a learning library online? The web app hosting should be a free one though, as this project is not commercial, and also it would be very nice to have Python behind the scenes.

N.B. The classifiers that should be supported by the library are multiclass svm and naive bayes.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying [google app engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine)? It has python (2.5 and 2.7) and can be [free](http://cloud.google.com/pricing/).

Comment: Can you recommend a machine learning library that will work on Google app engine?

Comment: Had a little look: google app engine doesn't support [egg modules](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/25EO1Arklfw), but does seem to support the use of [jars](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/ant). So go that would mean possibly going for java, in which case, for an ML library you could use [weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). Or you could price out a python host.